# How to display an RSS feed as a widget (or "badge") using PHP?

Tags: wordpress, rss, widget, feed

I have an RSS feed from a wp blog ([link](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RBloggers)), tunneled through feedburner, that I would like to display as a widget in another website.

The widget display can contain simply the headers taken from the feed, and the link to their respective posts.  I understand that there are many available web services for creating something like this (a few examples: [1](http://www.rssfeedwidget.com/), [2](http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/rss), [3](http://www.rsspump.com/))
But they all include a link to themselves, which I would like to save from the widget.

Instead, I would much rather have some php code on my server that will create this widget, so it could later be embedded into the other site like this:

What php code can perform this?  (I have seen [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712281/how-do-have-an-rss-feed-displayed-in-php) which was asked two years ago, but the answers didn't include any examples)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the widgets from http://www.rssfeedwidget.com/ to display your rss feed.